# sed command to replace string

Tags: linux

I was trying to replace %2$u with

```
 <ph name='NUMBER' ex='%2$u'/>
```

across multiple files using the following command.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/%2$u/<ph name='NUMBER' ex='%2$u'\/>/g'
```

And actually %2$u is getting replaced like this

```
<ph name=NUMBER ex=%2/>
```

Can someone give me the solution? Thanks in advance.

-Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed a single quote inside a single quoted string.  Try:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print |
  xargs sed -i 's/%2$u/<ph name='"'"'NUMBER'"'"' ex='"'"'%2$u'"'"'\/>/g'
```

or

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print |
    xargs sed -i "s/%2\$u/<ph name='NUMBER' ex='%2\$u'\/>/g"
```

Depending on the version of sed, you may need to escape the $ to sed to prevent it from only matching end of line:

```
xargs sed -i "s/%2\\\$u/<ph name='NUMBER' ex='%2\\\$u'\/>/g"
```

Comment: `$` will need to be escaped either way, no?

Comment: Inside the single quoted string, you do not need to escape the `$` for the shell.  Some versions of `sed` will not match it against end of line if it does not appear at the end of the pattern, but to be safe it probably should be escaped to sed.

Answer (score 0):

When [quoting with single quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes), the very next single quote ends the quoting. So the latter expression actually consists of these parts:

```
's/%2$u/<ph name='
NUMBER
' ex='
%2$u
'\/>/g'
```

And within the unquoted parts, [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) takes place. So `$u` is getting replaced by the value of the parameter `u`, or the empty string, if not existing. You can test this with a simple `echo`:

```
echo 's/%2$u/<ph name='NUMBER' ex='%2$u'\/>/g'
```

To avoid this, either use different quoting technique, e. g. double quotes for the parts containing single quotes (remember to escape the `$` in it, otherwise expansion takes place):

```
's/%2$u/<ph name='"'NUMBER'"' ex='"'%2\$u'"'\/>/g'
```

Or use double quotes within the replaced string, if applicable:

```
's/%2$u/<ph name="NUMBER" ex="%2$u"\/>/g'
```